# Retrieve messages from MySQL DB - Strophe/EJabberd

Tags: javascript, mysql, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I'm succesfully storing messages in the table `archive` but I don't know exactly how to retrieve them and paint them in the screen when opening a conversation.
I've tried sending this iq when clicking on a contact:

```
    var iq =  $iq({type: 'set'}).c('query', {xmlns: 'urn:xmpp:mam:1'}).
 c('x',{xmlns:'jabber:x:data',type:'submit'}).c('field',{var:'FORM_TYPE',type:'hidden'})
 .c('value','urn:xmpp:mam:1').up().up().c('field',{'var':'with'}).c('value',userID);`
```

which creates this:

```
<iq type="set" xmlns="jabber:client">
<query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:1">
  <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit">
   <field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden">
     <value>urn:xmpp:mam:1</value>
   </field>
   <field var="with">
     <value>"to@jid"</value>
   </field>
  </x>
 </query>
</iq>
```

I've also tried this:

```
conn.mam.query("from@jid", {
      "with": "to@jid",
      onMessage: function(message) {
                console.log("Message from ", $(message).find("forwarded message").attr("from"),
                    ": ", $(message).find("forwarded message body").text());
                return true;
      },
      onComplete: function(response) {
                console.log("Got all the messages");
      }
        });
```

But none of them is giving me anything to work with.

So, how can I get those messages?

Regards!!

**EDIT**
All I'm getting is this:

```
<iq from='me@jabber.local' to='me@jabber.local/42842339324235106273178' type='result'>
    <fin xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:1' complete='true'>
        <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
            <first>1462872928907929</first>
            <last>1462948310651516</last>
            <count>6</count>
        </set>
    </fin>
</iq>
```

Comment: Which version of ejabberd are you using ? What do you get as reply ?

Comment: @MickaëlRémond I've reedited the question. That's what I'm actually getting.

Comment: @MickaëlRémond Can you help me, please? There's no documentation on how to do this on the internet and I'm getting really frustrated...

Comment: I bileave you want retrieve the user's previous chats in the chat screen. I implemented this by storing the received messages on my local database. This is what watsapp also does. Here is my project without dbms implementation. I will update this with my dbms implementation using cordova-sqlite-storage.  https://github.com/arjunsk/Ionic-Chat-App